# How to make relative layout scrollable : Android

Tags: android

I am trying to make display complete address in Drop Details Section but due to large text some parts is getting hidden.

Here is my layout :

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        class="com.dmo.deliverypartner.Common.helpers.WorkaroundMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    <!-- Image View that acts as map marker notice centerInParent-->
    <!--<ImageView-->
    <!--android:id="@+id/imgViewMarkerLocation"-->
    <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
    <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
    <!--android:layout_centerInParent="true"-->
    <!--android:src="@mipmap/ic_pin"-->
    <!--android:visibility="visible" />-->


</RelativeLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtViewPickUpLocation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/header_height"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/drawable_round_corner_back_yellow"
    android:text="Drop Location"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:textColor="@color/color_white"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="@dimen/header_text_size"
    android:gravity="center"/>



<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relLayPickLocationBottom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="255dp"
    android:background="@drawable/drawable_top_corner_round"
    android:paddingTop="15dp"
    android:paddingRight="15dp"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:overScrollMode="ifContentScrolls"
    android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtViewStoreDetails"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Drop Details"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/color_white"/>



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtViewStoreDetails"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtViewCurrentLocationTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Current Location - "
                android:textSize="13sp"
                android:textColor="@color/color_white"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtViewCurrentLocation"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="xyz"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                android:textColor="@color/color_white"/>

        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtViewStoreNameTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Name -  "
                android:textSize="13sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:textColor="@color/color_white"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtViewStoreName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=""
                android:textSize="13sp"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:textColor="@color/color_white"/>

        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtViewAreaTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Area -  "
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                android:textColor="@color/color_white"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtViewArea"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=""
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                android:textColor="@color/color_white"/>

        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtViewStreetTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Street -  "
                android:textSize="13sp"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@color/color_white"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtViewStreet"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=""

                android:textSize="13sp"
                android:textColor="@color/color_white"/>

        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtViewLandmarkTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Landmark -  "
                android:textSize="13sp"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@color/color_white"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtViewLandmark"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=""
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                android:textColor="@color/color_white"/>

        </LinearLayout>


        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/color_white"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>




        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:background="@drawable/drawable_round_corner_with_stroke">



            <com.dmo.deliverypartner.Common.slider.SlideToUnlock
                android:id="@+id/sliderDropLocation"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="13dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                app:sliderColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                app:cornerRadiusX="1dp"
                app:slideToUnlockText="Drop Order"
                app:cornerRadiusY="2dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"  />




        </RelativeLayout>



        <!--
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtViewNavigate"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Navigate"
                        android:textColor="#8a8a8a"
                        android:background="@drawable/drawable_round_corner_with_stroke"
                        android:paddingTop="13dp"
                        android:paddingBottom="13dp"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>-->


    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgNavigateToLocation"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_60_dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/relLayPickLocationBottom"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="17dp"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_nev" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgMakeCall"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_60_dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/relLayPickLocationBottom"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="299dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="17dp"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_call" />
```

I am trying to make the contents above Drop Order Button to be scrollable suuch that it displays the complete address.

Image how my design is coming:
[image]

Layout:

[image]

Comment: I am trying to add that but it doesnot works and shows errors while building

Comment: For whichever layout you want to make scrollable, you can wrap it inside ScrollView or NestedScrollView.